# How to resolve error Salt must be 8 bytes long

Tags: itext, digital-signature, keystore, pfx, digital

I am writing a program to sign a pdf using certificate (pfx file). For few of the certificates I am getting below exception.

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Salt must be at least 8 bytes long
```

This happens when I execute the below code.

```
Keystore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
```

I am getting an exception in the below java file at line number 123.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/com/sun/crypto/provider/HmacPKCS12PBESHA1.java?av=h

Answer (score 2):

Your keystore has one or more certificate(s) that has a salt length which is less than 8. The crypto program requires atleast 8 bytes.

I would recommend creating a new keystore with just the one certificate that you need and try signing with that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the exception using pkcs12-DEF keystore. I have added my code lines below.

```
BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(provider);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12-DEF");
```

Earlier I had not added BountyCastleProvider to Security, because of which I was not able to get instance of pkcs12-DEF keystore. 
Apart from this I have also downloaded jar files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html location and replaced it with jar files present in Java\Jdk1.7\jre\lib\security. These are JCE 7 Unlimited strength policy files.